PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access denied. IN WIN11
When I was using ultralytics' model.tune, an error occurred: PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied.
I have ensured that my current user account has full access permissions, and I am using a terminal with administrator privileges within Visual Studio Code (VSCode). My code is running in a virtual environment created by Miniconda.
I am able to use model.train from ultralytics to train models without any issues. However, when I try to use model.tune to adjust hyperparameters, the above problem occurs. I am not using rat_tune. Below is the code.python=3.9.19
from ultralytics import YOLO


# Load a YOLOv8n model
model = YOLO(r'yolov8m.pt')

# Start tuning hyperparameters for YOLOv8n training on the COCO8 dataset
model.tune(data=r'coco8.yaml', epochs=1000, batch=16, device='0')



I tried restarting my computer, setting the temp folder to not be read-only, turning off real-time protection in Windows Defender, and using the global environment instead of a virtual one. However, when using the global environment, I couldn't even install the required dependencies, so I decided to continue using the virtual environment.

just add os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'。this is OMP: Error #15: Initializing libiomp5md.dll, but found libiomp5md.dll already initialized.but present PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access denied

This looks like an addition to the problem description, so it is better to add it to the original message.
